# How to generate HAR file after running a test using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have created a script in JMeter using Selenium jar and I have written script in WebDriver sample using Java script language .

Script is working fine

```
//var pkg2 = JavaImporter(net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxy);

var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium); //WebDriver classes
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait); //WebDriver classes
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000);

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart(); //captures sampler's start time
WDS.sampleResult.getLatency();
WDS.log.info("Sample started");

WDS.browser.get('http://newtours.demoaut.com/mercuryreservation.php'); //opens website specified in 'http://duckduckgo.com'
WDS.log.info("Sample ended - navigated to flight reservation.com");


var btnView = WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Mercury')]"))
WDS.browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", btnView)

WDS.log.info(btnView.parameters);
WDS.log.info(btnView.size);
var username=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//input[@name='userName']"));

username.sendKeys([WDS.parameters]);

var password=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//input[@name='password']"));
password.sendKeys(['mypassword']);


var login=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.xpath("//input[@value='Login']"));
login.click();
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd();
```

Now I Would like to generate HAR file(HTTP Water fall) in JMeter.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Please tell why the Jmeter is only generating 1KB file after execution.
and when we open the same on LoadRunner, no call are recorded. Regards
Gaurav

Answer (score 2):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of your WebDriver Sampler
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   def proxy = new net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxyServer()
   proxy.setHarCaptureTypes(net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.CaptureType.getAllContentCaptureTypes())
   proxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT, net.lightbody.bmp.proxy.CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT)
   proxy.newHar()
   proxy.start(8888)
   vars.putObject('proxy',proxy)
   ```
3. Configure your browser to use the [BrowserMobProxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) for all traffic

   [image: Selenium BrowserMob JMeter]
4. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the WebDriver Sampler and out the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def proxy = vars.getObject('proxy')

   proxy.getHar().writeTo(new File("/path/to/your/file.har"))
   proxy.stop()
   ```

You can learn more about Groovy scripting in JMeter via [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri.. This code works but Har file is not generated in proper manner. It always shown 1 KB file after TR executing.

Answer (score 0):

Please share the sample script if you have anything because I tried the above process but unable to generate the HAR file and below is the error message

> 2019-07-18 11:56:59,920 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling
>   threadStarted org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: invalid
>   argument: cannot parse capability: proxy from invalid argument:
>   Specifying 'socksProxy' requires an integer for 'socksVersion'
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402
>   (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 16 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision:
>   '4c2593cfc3689a7fcd7be52549167e5ccc93ad28', time: '2016-02-11
>   11:22:43' System info: host: 'PC0CRTUU', ip: '10.115.42.113', os.name:
>   'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_181' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver  at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor61.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_181]    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>   ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.52.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>   ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.52.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>   ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.52.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
>   ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.52.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>   ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.52.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
>   ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.52.0.jar:?]    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:170)
>   ~[selenium-chrome-driver-2.52.0.jar:?]    at
>   com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:74)
>   ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]     at
>   com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig.createBrowser(ChromeDriverConfig.java:21)
>   ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]     at
>   com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.getPreparedBrowser(WebDriverConfig.java:233)
>   ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]     at
>   com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.WebDriverConfig.threadStarted(WebDriverConfig.java:220)
>   ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:762)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]  at
>   org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:994)
>   [jorphan.jar:5.0 r1840935]    at
>   org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:977)
>   [jorphan.jar:5.0 r1840935]    at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:730)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]  at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:718)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]  at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source) [?:1.8.0_181] 2019-07-18 11:56:59,954 ERROR
>   o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223
>   PreProcessor javax.script.ScriptException:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: Script5.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class
>   net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxyServer   @ line 1, column 13.    def
>   proxy = new net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxyServer()
>                  ^

1 error

> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.compile(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:187)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:215)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor.process(JSR223PreProcessor.java:44)
>   [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.0 r1840935]    at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:935)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]  at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:537)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]  at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]  at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source) [?:1.8.0_181] Caused by:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: Script5.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class
>   net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxyServer   @ line 1, column 13.    def
>   proxy = new net.lightbody.bmp.BrowserMobProxyServer()
>                  ^

1 error

> at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:981)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:626)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:575)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:323)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:293)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:236)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.getScriptClass(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:335)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.compile(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:185)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   ... 7 more 2019-07-18 11:56:59,969
>   ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223
>   PreProcessor javax.script.ScriptException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getHar() on null
>   object    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_181]   at
>   org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:221)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor.process(JSR223PreProcessor.java:44)
>   [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.0 r1840935]    at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:935)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]  at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:537)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]  at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]  at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source) [?:1.8.0_181] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:
>   Cannot invoke method getHar() on null object  at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:47)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:34)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   at Script6.run(Script6.groovy:3)
>   ~[?:?]    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:321)
>   ~[groovy-all-2.4.15.jar:2.4.15]   ... 9 more 2019-07-18 11:56:59,970
>   ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler:
>   'TC01_Purdy_Homepage'. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Browser has
>   not been configured.  Please ensure at least 1 WebDriverConfig is
>   created for a ThreadGroup.    at
>   com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:62)
>   ~[jmeter-plugins-webdriver-3.0.jar:?]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
>   ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]     at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]  at
>   org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
>   [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.0 r1840935]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source) [?:1.8.0_181] 2019-07-18 11:56:59,971 INFO
>   o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1 2019-07-18
>   11:56:59,971 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group
>   1-1 2019-07-18 11:56:59,971 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine:
>   Notifying test listeners of end of test 2019-07-18 11:56:59,971 INFO
>   o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)